# Does the UK immigration board require a degree for programmers?

Tags: immigration, qualifications

According to [this](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/skilled-worker-visa-shortage-occupations/skilled-worker-visa-shortage-occupations) programmers are on the UK skills shortages list. Do you need to have a college degree to qualify? I suspect so but I cannot find anything about education requirements.

What exactly are the experience / education requirements for programmers wishing to immigrate to the UK?

Comment: Not necessarily. Searching ‘Programmer’ in the ONS occupation coding tool on that site results in a long-ish list of roles. A random check of a couple of the roles indicates that entrants usually possess a degree or equivalent qualification, although entry with other academic qualifications and/or significant relevant experience is possible.

Answer (score 1):

The immigration authorities won't require a degree, but...  You will need a job as a programmer with a specific company.  That will be hard without a degree unless you have extensive experience, as a programmer, in your home country.

The immigration authorities may look rather harder at an application without a degree (they will want to be sure this isn't an immigration scam), but there is no particular reason that they wouldn't grant your visa.

Comment: Probably better to just to get one. As I suspected.